# Website and Database: Check if username exists

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to know how to check if the given username exists in my MySQL database table. Table name is `users`. But it seems to bypass my `if` statement, and go right ahead and add the username anyway, causing my table to have duplicates of the same username.

I have been using Mysqli since that is what we are supposed to use now. Here is the latest method I have tried. I know this isn't quite prepared from defending against SQL injection, I am not worried about that just yet. I am just trying to get this thing to work first, then I will add the security.

My database login info is stored on a separate php file named "credentials.php".

```
<?php
$password1 = ($_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = ($_POST['pass2']);
$firstname = ($_POST['fname']);
$lastname = ($_POST['lname']);
$username = ($_POST['user']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);     

/*
include_once 'credentials.php';
$dbhandle = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database); 
 */
// Check if any fields are empty
if (empty($_POST['fname']) or empty($_POST['lname']) or empty($_POST['user']) or empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['pass1']) or empty($_POST['pass2'])){
?>
<div class="ERRORBOX">
<?php
 // Empty Fields ERROR
    echo "You must enter data into ALL of the fields to register. Please try again.";
    header( "refresh:5;url=../index.php" );
?>
    <p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">5</span> second(s).</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function countdown() {
        var i = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
            location.href = 'login.php';
        }
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    }
    setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
    </script>
</div>
<?php
} else {
    // Check if passwords match
    if ($password1 !== $password2) {
    ?>
    <div class="ERRORBOX">
    <?php
    // Password mismatch ERROR
        echo "You entered two different passwords! Please try again.";
        header( "refresh:5;url=../index.php" );
    ?>
        <p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">5</span> second(s).</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function countdown() {
            var i = document.getElementById('counter');
            if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
                location.href = 'login.php';
            }
            i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
        }
        setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
        </script>
    </div>
    <?php
    } else {    
        // Create connection
        include_once 'credentials.php';
        $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        // Check if username exists <<<THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE<<<<<
        $username = ($_POST['user']);
        
        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            echo "That username already exists.";   
            $conn->close();
        }
        else{
            //IT JUST SKIPS THE CODE ABOVE AND GOES STRAIGHT TO THE ONE BELOW
            $firstname = ($_POST['fname']);
            $lastname = ($_POST['lname']);
            $username = ($_POST['user']);
            $email = ($_POST['email']);
            $password = ($_POST['pass1']);
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
        
            // Create connection
            include_once 'credentials.php';
            $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);        
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `sign_up_date`, `email`, `email_activation`, `permit`, `status`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `ipv4`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password', NOW(), '$email', '0', 'c', 'a', '$firstname', '$lastname', '1985-01-01', '$ipaddress')";
                
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    header('Location: ../success.php');
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }        
                $conn->close();        
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't check if the username already exists, simply put a `UNIQUE` constraint in your database for the username column. Then attempt to insert, if `$conn->error()` is set then you know that the username already exists.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: If you manually run the query on the db, are you getting results for this?

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'

for the exact same username you are trying to use?

Comment: Ok I see about the unique contstraint. So that locks any column you select for it. Thats cool. Wish I knew about that before. Thanks. So, I just completely took out the entire check if username exists block. But now, instead of passing forward to the insert code block, it just displays a blank page.

Comment: use $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

Answer (score 2):

First of all when you want the value of a row in the database table to appear only once you need to specify that column as `UNIQUE`. So start by altering the `users` table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN username username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

After you've done that, if your script tries to insert a row in the database that contains a username that has already been used, that row won't insert and you won't have duplicates. But that's not enough, you need a way to inform the user that the username they want is already in use, so that's where your PHP script comes in.

Your script isn't working because you call `mysqli_query` without the database connection object.

There are two ways you can call `mysql_query`:

- Using the procedural style: `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");`
- Going OOP-style: `$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");`

You call `mysqli_query` in a procedural style without giving it a connection object. Change it to one of the above and it will work

Comment: mysqli_query is designed to the called with the query as the first and only param as well.

Comment: I did. See this

`mixed mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

In this, you can use $query as the only mandatory param.

Comment: @phreakv6 That's OOP-style, the one I mention in the second bullet. It says: `mysqli::query` that's a scope resolution operator meaning the `query` method of an instance of the `mysqli` class. This is the prototype for the procedural style: `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )` it needs a link

Comment: Either way, use prepared statements

Comment: @Strawberry I agree, it's just that OP said he knows about SQL Injection and what he needs to do, so I assumed he just wants a reason why his code is not working

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend just adding a UNIQUE constraint to your table column.

Run the following query in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT ux_username UNIQUE (username)
```

Now don't do any checks, simply insert your new user and check `$conn->error()`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `sign_up_date`, `email`, `email_activation`, `permit`, `status`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `ipv4`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, '0', 'c', 'a', ?, ?, '1985-01-01', ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $email, $firstname, $lastname, $ipaddress);
$stmt->execute();

if (empty($conn->error())) {
    header('Location: ../success.php');
    exit; //remember to exit after redirections
} else {
    echo 'Username already exists.';
}
```

Also I changed your code to properly insert the data. Inserting raw user input is dangerous as there might be a loose single quote or semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE(`username`);
```

This will prevent the duplicate inserts. You should still try to figure out why you are having issues with that mysqli_num_rows. I suggest you run the query manually and see if it returns results.

Comment: no matter what i run in the query, any block of code, i get this exact same message:

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'include_once 'credentials.php'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You have used mysqli_query in wrong manner 
either use

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='$username'");
```

or use

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='$username'");
```

Answer (score -1):

FOUND A SOLUTION. I think the guy who came up with the solution deleted his answer. So I will post it here: (By the way, thanks everyone. Your answers were helpful too.)

```
<?php

$password1 = ($_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = ($_POST['pass2']);
$firstname = ($_POST['fname']);
$lastname = ($_POST['lname']);
$username = ($_POST['user']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);




// Check if any fields are empty
if (empty($_POST['fname']) or empty($_POST['lname']) or empty($_POST['user']) or empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['pass1']) or empty($_POST['pass2'])){
 ?><div class="ERRORBOX"><?php
 // Empty Fields ERROR
echo "You must enter data into ALL of the fields to register. Please try again.";
header( "refresh:5;url=../index.php" );
 ?>
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">5</span> second(s).</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'login.php';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
</div>
<?php


} else {
// Check if passwords match
if ($password1 !== $password2) {
?><div class="ERRORBOX"><?php
// Password mismatch ERROR
    echo "You entered two different passwords! Please try again.";
header( "refresh:5;url=../index.php" );
?>
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">5</span> second(s).</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'login.php';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
</div>
<?php



} else {    

 // Create connection
          include_once 'credentials.php';
          $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
          // Check connection
          if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
          }


          // Check if username exists 
          $username = ($_POST['user']);
          $qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'"; 
          $query = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
?><div class="ERRORBOX"><?php
               echo "That username already exists.";
?></div><?php


}else{

          // Check if email exists 
          $email= ($_POST['email']);
          $qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'"; 
          $query = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
?><div class="ERRORBOX"><?php
               echo "That email is already registered.";
?></div><?php
               $conn->close();




 }else{

$firstname = ($_POST['fname']);
 $lastname = ($_POST['lname']);
 $username = ($_POST['user']);
 $email = ($_POST['email']);
 $password = ($_POST['pass1']);
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

// Create connection
include_once 'credentials.php';
$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

 }else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `username`, `password`, `sign_up_date`, `email`, `email_activation`, `permit`, `status`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `ipv4`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password', NOW(), '$email', '0', 'c', 'a', '$firstname', '$lastname', '1985-01-01', '$ipaddress')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: ../success.php');
exit;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

}

$conn->close();

}
}
}
}
}

?>
```